# Is it possible to sort multidimensional hashes by child hash values?

Tags: ruby, hash

Is is possible to sort parent hashes by values of children keys?

For example:

```
{
    :a => 
        {:order => 3},
    :b =>
        {:order => 1},
    :c =>
        {:order => 2}
}
```

resorted as

```
{
    :b => 
        {:order => 1},
    :c =>
        {:order => 2},
    :a =>
        {:order => 3}
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind hashes are intended to be un-ordered containers. Ruby supports only one method of ordering: Insertion order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it to an array of pairs, use [`sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) method to target the value you want to sort by, and then convert it back to a hash:

```
h = {
    :a => 
        {:order => 3},
    :b =>
        {:order => 1},
    :c =>
        {:order => 2}
}

h.sort_by {|k,v| v[:order]}.to_h
=> {:b=>{:order=>1}, :c=>{:order=>2}, :a=>{:order=>3}}
```

Comment: Close, but you need to reassemble those back into a Hash if that's the goal.

Comment: I only noticed this after the fact. By then others had already done it.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the only order that a Ruby hash can have is based on insertion order. You need to create a new hash (no `sort!`) and create the new hash element by element in the order you wish it to have.

Given:

```
> hash
=> {:a=>{:order=>3}, :b=>{:order=>1}, :c=>{:order=>2}}
```

You can use `.sort_by` to do:

```
> hash.sort_by {|k, h| h[:order]}.to_h
=> {:b=>{:order=>1}, :c=>{:order=>2}, :a=>{:order=>3}}
```

You can also use the more classic `.sort` with the spaceship `<=>` by unpacking the arguments associated with the usual `a,b`:

```
> hash.sort {|(a,ha),(b,hb)| ha[:order] <=> hb[:order] }.to_h
=> {:b=>{:order=>1}, :c=>{:order=>2}, :a=>{:order=>3}}
```

In either case, the `.to_h` method creates a new hash based on the sorted key, value pairs from the source hash.

Best